# Stack overflow with Spring-boot-actuator 1.5.22 and spring 5.2.17

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Application startup failed

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpointHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [com/myorg/api/web/AppConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.17.RELEASE.jar:5.2.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.17.RELEASE.jar:5.2.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.17.RELEASE.jar:5.2.17.RELEASE]
    at
```

<----------The AppConfig.java----------------->

```
package com.myorg.api.web;

import com.myorg.api.web.properties.ThreadPoolProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MvcEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig
{
  private static final String BUNDLE_API_THREAD_NAME_PREFIX = "BUNDLE-API-THREAD-";
  private static final String HISTORICAL_API_THREAD_NAME_PREFIX = "HISTORICAL-API-THREAD-";

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "historical-api-thread-pool")
  public ThreadPoolProperties historicalApiThreadPool()
  {
    return new ThreadPoolProperties();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bundle-api-thread-pool")
  public ThreadPoolProperties bundleApiThreadPool()
  {
    return new ThreadPoolProperties();
  }

  @Bean
  public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bundleAPIThreadPoolTaskExecutor(final ThreadPoolProperties bundleApiThreadPool)
  {
    return createThreadPoolTaskExecutor(bundleApiThreadPool.getCorePoolSize(), bundleApiThreadPool.getMaxPoolSize(),
        bundleApiThreadPool.getQueueCapacity(), bundleApiThreadPool.isAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(),
        bundleApiThreadPool.getKeepAliveSeconds(), BUNDLE_API_THREAD_NAME_PREFIX);
  }

  @Bean
  public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor historicalAPIThreadPoolTaskExecutor(final ThreadPoolProperties historicalApiThreadPool)
  {
    return createThreadPoolTaskExecutor(historicalApiThreadPool.getCorePoolSize(),
        historicalApiThreadPool.getMaxPoolSize(),
        historicalApiThreadPool.getQueueCapacity(), historicalApiThreadPool.isAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(),
        historicalApiThreadPool.getKeepAliveSeconds(), HISTORICAL_API_THREAD_NAME_PREFIX);
  }

  private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor createThreadPoolTaskExecutor(Integer threadPoolCorePoolSize,
      Integer threadPoolMaxPoolSize, int threadPoolQueueCapacity,
      boolean threadPoolAllowCoreThreadTimeOut, int threadPoolKeepAliveSeconds,
      String threadNamePrefix)
  {
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

    if (threadPoolCorePoolSize != null)
    {
      pool.setCorePoolSize(threadPoolCorePoolSize);
    }
    else
    {
      pool.setCorePoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    }

    if (threadPoolMaxPoolSize != null)
    {
      pool.setMaxPoolSize(threadPoolMaxPoolSize);
    }
    else
    {
      pool.setMaxPoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2);
    }

    pool.setQueueCapacity(threadPoolQueueCapacity);
    pool.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(threadPoolAllowCoreThreadTimeOut);
    pool.setKeepAliveSeconds(threadPoolKeepAliveSeconds);
    pool.setThreadNamePrefix(threadNamePrefix);
    pool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    pool.initialize();

    return pool;
  }

  @Bean(name = "mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector")
  public HandlerMappingIntrospector mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector() {
    return new HandlerMappingIntrospector();
  }
}
```

Comment: You should show at least the code of `com/myorg/api/web/AppConfig.class`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are using incompatible versions, don't do that. Spring Boot 1.5 is for Spring 4.x not 5.x, trying to shoehorn that into 5.x will not work. Either upgrade to the prope Spring Boot version or ditch all that managing of dependencies.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum. Yes I figured that out yesterday. I need to use Spring 4.3.25 with spring boot 1.5.22. So there is no way to use Spring 5 with an older version of Spring Boot 1.5.22 ?

Comment: No there isn't. Not without weird issues and no garantuees that it (keeps) works.